# Scheme to verify AES key was correctly encrypted for public key recipient

Tags: rsa, aes, verifiability

In our file sharing scenario there are three participants: $A$, $B$ and $C$. Each participant has a public-private key pair (let's assume RSA for now). $A$ wants to share a symmetric AES key $k$ with the other participants. $B$ is given access to the file for free, while $C$ has to pay a fee for it. Thus, $A$ may potentially cheat $C$ by providing a wrong key $k'$, and $B$ should be able to act as an arbitrator in case of dispute.

The sequence is as follows:

- $A$ first shares the AES key $k$ with $B$ by encrypting it with $B$'s
  public key and makes it available to $B$. Now $A$ and $B$ have access
  to the symmetric AES key.
- Then, $A$ shares the same key $k$ with $C$ by encrypting it with
  $C$'s public key, making the ciphertext available to all
  participants.
- $B$ should now be able to prove that the ciphertext
  provided to $C$ is indeed the key $k$ encrypted with $C$'s public
  key.

This would be possible by using textbook RSA, where the ciphertext is deterministic. Since [textbook RSA is insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/if-rsa-is-only-used-to-encrypt-symmetric-keys-which-are-random-whats-wrong-wit), this is not an option. I take it that this is similar to [key escrow schemes/verifiable encryption](https://www.shoup.net/papers/verenc.pdf), but I've been unable to figure out a scheme/crypto implementation for the proposed scenario.

Comment: You could run a [socialist millionaire's protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires) between $B$ and $C$ so they can check whether they have the same $k$ without revealing it.

Comment: This is a valid idea, but it doesn't prove whether $A$ misbehaved and sent the wrong key. $C$ can influence the outcome of the socialist millionaire protocol (i.e. to blame $A$ even though $A$ sent the correct key). Ideally, the scheme should be non-interactive ($B$ can prove that the ciphertext is correct/incorrect based on knowledge of $k$ and $C$'s public key) or interactive between verifier $B$ and prover $A$.

Comment: Suppose $c=\operatorname{Enc}_{\text{pk}_C}(k;r)$ is the ciphertext $A$ sends to $C$ using the randomness $r$. What stops you from having $A$ and $C$ send $c$ to $B$ and additionally have $A$ send $r$ to $B$ and then $B$ reproduces the now-deterministic encryption of $c$ using the known-good $k'$ $B$ has to check whether $c\stackrel{?}{=}\operatorname{Enc}_{\text{pk}_C}(k';r)$. If you're feeling fancy and don't want to just send over $r$ you could either encrypt it for $B$ or if you're feeling really fancy run a zero-knowledge proof of the above.

Comment: Thanks, I thinks this works well enough. I'll gladly accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This would be possible by using textbook RSA, where the ciphertext is deterministic

You have the right idea there, that a deterministic scheme is the way to go. However note that every scheme is deterministic if you explicitly fix the randomness used.

So suppose you encrypt $k$ for $C$ as $c=\operatorname{Enc}_{\text{pk}_C}(k;r)$ using $C$'s public key and the randomness $r$. Now for the arbitration you give $k$ to $B$ who checks that the $k$ actually is the correct one. Then you have $C$ send the received $c$ (call it $c_C$) to $B$ and have $A$ send the sent $c$ (call it $c_A$) along with the randomness $r$ used for the encryption to $B$. You could possibly encrypt the randomness here using $B$'s public key. Then $B$ re-computes $c'=\operatorname{Enc}_{\text{pk}_C}(k;r)$ using the received randomness and its own known $k$ and checks whether $c'$ matches $c_A$ and $c_B$. If it matches at least $c_B$ then $A$ was honest (because then $B$ got the right key). If it only matches $c_A$ then either of $A$ or $B$ is lying but we don't know which, because $B$ could have produced its own ciphertext and sent it to $B$ or $A$ could have produced a correct ciphertext for $B$ but sent a bad one to $C$. I don't think there is a way to resolve this issue and find out who lied at the end.